# Bamboo Continuous integration with yarn test (JEST framework)

Tags: bamboo

I am very new to Atlassian Bamboo build CI. I want some help from you guys.

My Job is to make a continuous integration build plan for my reactjs application. So I started with Bamboo.

Now my application test cases are written in JEST framework.

In my (local machine) react application when I test the test cases locally I use the following command

"yarn test"

I installed yarn inside Bamboo by "npm install yarn"

My requirement is whenever I will merge my code in GitHub an automatic build will be triggered in Bamboo and if the test cases are passed then it will deploy the code..Now the build plan is getting triggered when ever I merge the code it GitHub (Because in step 1 of the build plan I made a job to checkout code from my GitHub repo)

But I am not understanding how to tell the build plan to run "yarn test" my test cases using JEST framework.

The question might look very easy for you guys...so please help me..

Answer (score 2):

The agent (local or remote) running your builds needs:

1. Nodejs installed
2. npm installed - typically by the nodejs install
3. yarn installed globally (npm i -g yarn)

Then you can use as a script task to run the yarn test command.

You can build on this be seeing if there are plugins that abstract the script task into some sort of yarn task and you can look at processing the test results in Bamboo so that the builds show the test results and fail/pass the build accorindly.